# Is it possible to have one node_module folder for multiple projects in a repository?

Tags: javascript, git, gruntjs, npm

asume that we have a repository name REPO which is includes several grunt projects. And let's asume we want that the structure:

```
ROOT
-- bower_components
-- node_modules
-- project_1
-- project_2
-- project_3 etc
```

Now the issue is that i need for each project a different gruntfile.js so i can have for example a different distributed minified js file, different tasks etc.

The solution i've got for now but isn't at all helpfull is that each project folder has it's own node_module folder with all the needed modules.

So i;ve got this and i want to change it like the schema above.

```
ROOT
-- bower_components
-- project_1
---- node_modules
-- project_2
---- node_modules
-- project_3
---- node_modules
```

Now each gruntfile looks like that:

```
function config(name) {
  return require ('./tasks/' + name + '.js');
}

module.exports = function (grunt){

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    jshint: config('jshint'),
    concat: config('concat'),
    uglify: config('uglify'),
    cssmin: config('cssmin'),
    jsbeautifier: config('jsbeautifier'),
    watch: {
      options: {livereload: true},
      files: ['index.html', 'app/views/**/*.html', 'app/css/*.css', 'js/*.js'],
      tasks: ['jshint']
    },
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/test.conf.js'
      }
    }

  });

  //load plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jsbeautifier');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');

  //tasks
  grunt.registerTask('dist', ['jshint', 'concat', 'uglify', 'cssmin', 'jsbeautifier']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```

Can i add a path for each NpmTask instead of installing the modules for each project in my REPO?

Please if you need more info or my English are bad ask me anything and i'll update my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [load-grunt-parent-tasks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-grunt-parent-tasks) to do that.

I recognize I did not use this plugin, but I think I will help you.

Comment: Is possible to update your answer with an example taken from my gruntfile above?

Comment: As i see this plugin still creates a node_module folder in each subproject. That could potential give me a huge .gitignore file as the projects in that repo could easily be over 1000 soon.

Comment: You can add "**/node_modules/" to your gitignore.